# How to display message in webpage using thymeleaf + spark-java web framework?

Tags: java, thymeleaf, spark-java

I am writing a small web app using spark-java. I have used thymeleaf as template engine and intellij is the IDE I have been using. The problem I am facing is that variable is not rendering in webpage as it should have.

I have passed `todaysdate` attribute to the template engine

```
public void init() {
    Spark.staticFiles.location("/templates");
    get("/", (req, res) -> {
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        DateModel dateModel = getDate();
        String date = "Monday 6, May 2019";
        model.put("todaysdate", date);
        return render(model, "index");
    });
}

private String render(Map<String, Object> model, String pageName){
    return new ThymeleafTemplateEngine().render(
            new ModelAndView(model, pageName)
    );
}
```

My html code contains the following code snipped

```
<div class="col-2 date" id="currentdate" th:text="${todaysdate}"></div>
```

But the text is not displayed on the webpage. Intellij is saying cannot resolve `todaysdate`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it will be displayed if the following code is removed.

```
Spark.staticFiles.location("/templates");
```

Because, ThymeleafTemplateEngine uses files under "/templates".
If staticFiles.location is specified, that takes precedence.
Therefore, index.html which is not templated is output.